# ios share extention stopped working after adding admob to React native project

Tags: ios, admob

I have managed iOS share Action extension which is stop working when I added ad-mob.
I have tried to trouble shoot that issue but didn't get any lead why this is happening.
I have highlighted what I made custom from native side.
[image]

Comment: did you find solution?